# How to use variable from inner select in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables

```
table : tab1
id serial primary key
val integer
```

and

```
table : tab2
id serial primary key
val2 integer
```

Now I tried this query

```
select id, (select id from tab2) as id2 from tab1
```

It is working fine. But when I tried to use `id2` in `where` clause, it is giving error.

```
select id, (select id from tab2) as id2 from tab1 where id2 = id
```

Comment: Why don't you just join the two tables?

Comment: may be this `select id, (select id from tab2 where id=your_value) as id2 from tab1` ?

Comment: Could you elaborate `where id2 = id`, what you want to do actually ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I don't understand, it should be as simple as this:

```
select T1.id
,      T2.id as id2 
from   tab1 T1
join   tab2 T2
    ON T1.id = T2.id
```

**edit based on comment**
I'm not very familiar with `mysql` syntax, but couldn't you put you query in a subquery? Like:

```
select   *
from     (select id, (select id from tab2) as id2 from tab1) a
where    a.id = a.id2
```

Comment: I cannot use join. I tried to simplify problem. actually I am getting values of other table from a procedure.

Comment: In that case, can you expand your simplification to show the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

As per OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174871/how-to-use-variable-from-inner-select-in-where-clause#comment56097054_34174983) Try this

```
select * from (
select arr, unnest('{1,2,3}'::int[]) as val 
from tab1 
)t
where val = any(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use alias from `select` statement in `where` clause. In your query, `id2` is the alias column name. Therefore you cannot use as `where id2 = id`. But you may use

```
select id, (select id from tab2) as id2 
from tab1 where id = (select id from tab2);
```

Or use JOIN query.

```
select tab1.id,tab2.id
from tab1, tab2
where tab1.id = tab2.id;
```